# Detect end of fling in HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, scroll, detect, horizontalscrollview, onfling

How can I detect the end of a fling event within a HorizontalScrollView?

Using a GestureDetector, I can determine when onFling has started, but I can't figure out how to tell when it has completed.  Is there any callback function or similar trick that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is late but probably useful with the similar requirements

My approach is to override scrollTo of the View.
With I reschedule a delayed message using a Handler.
The effect is that as long as scroll call happens the message will not be delivered.
But when no scroll call happens the message will be delivered and could be used to signal the end of "flinging"

Did you get the idea?

Comment: Thanks for writing after so long! I worked around the issue long ago, but this is an interesting solution. Unfortunately, I don't have time to test it right now, but I'll mark it as the answer since it seems like the "cleanest" solution.  I'll keep this in mind if I need to do something like this again someday. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it is better to override `View.onScrollChanged`: it is called in response to scrollTo and scrollBy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by detecting [an over scroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

---

How about this :

Use a combination of [`onFling()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onFling%28android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float%29) and [`onScrollChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). When an fling event occurs AND a scrolling event follows, you will get the exact amount of change.

Comment: That might work if the fling sent the view beyond its boundaries (overscroll), but there may be cases where it's a really long view and the fling stays within those boundaries.  I'm looking more for an event that's triggered or a flag that's set, etc.

Comment: In addition, OnOverScroll() API is not available on older API levels such as 8, etc.

Comment: From what i see, onFling() gets triggered after a series of onScroll() when i fling the HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work to visible and invisible the horizontal scrollView's scroll end

```
hsv.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            View view = (View) hsv.getChildAt(hsv.getChildCount() - 1);
            int diff = (view.getRight() - (hsv.getWidth() + hsv.getScrollX()));

            if (diff <= 0) {
                next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```